# Apache Spark with watermark - processing data different LogTypes in same kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, watermark

I'm using Apache Spark Structured Streaming to read data from Kafka topic, and do some processing. I'm using watermark to account for late-coming records and the code works fine.

Here is the working(sample) code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, to_timestamp, window, max,expr
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType,IntegerType

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("local[3]") \
        .appName("Sliding Window Demo") \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1) \
        .getOrCreate()


stock_schema = StructType([
        StructField("LogType", StringType()),
        StructField("CreatedTime", StringType()),
        StructField("Type", StringType()),
        StructField("Amount", IntegerType()),
        StructField("BrokerCode", StringType())
    ])

kafka_df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "trades") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()

value_df = kafka_df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), stock_schema).alias("value"))

trade_df = value_df.select("value.*") \
        .withColumn("CreatedTime", to_timestamp(col("CreatedTime"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) \
        .withColumn("Buy", expr("case when Type == 'BUY' then Amount else 0 end")) \
        .withColumn("Sell", expr("case when Type == 'SELL' then Amount else 0 end"))


window_agg_df = trade_df \
        .withWatermark("CreatedTime", "10 minute") \
        .groupBy(window(col("CreatedTime"), "10 minute")) \
        .agg({"Buy":"sum", "Sell":"sum"}).withColumnRenamed("sum(Buy)", "TotalBuy").withColumnRenamed("sum(Sell)", "TotalSell")

output_df = window_agg_df.select("window.start", "window.end", "TotalBuy", "TotalSell")

window_query = output_df.writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "chk-point-dir-mar28") \
        .trigger(processingTime="30 second") \
        .start()

window_query.awaitTermination()
```

Currently, I'm processing a single LogType, the requirement is to process multiple LogTypes in the same flow .. LogTypes will be config driven, and can change based on client.
Objective is to have generic code that can process all logTypes (config-driven)

As an example, for LogType X, I will need to get groupby columns col1, col2 and get the sum of values 'sent' & 'received'.
for LogType Y, the groupBy columns will remain the same but the sum will be on column col3 instead.

w/o the watermark, I can look at the LogType and do the processing in batch mode (using foreachbatch).
However, with watermark - i'm unable to figure out how to process based on LogType.

Any inputs on this ?

tia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add filter function to compare rows of a dataset

```
value_df = kafka_df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), stock_schema).alias("value"))
filtered = value_df.filter(value_df.LogType == "X")
```

Regarding "config driven", import `sys` or `argparse` modules to accept "log-type" flag when you run the script, and run multiple times for each type

```bash
spark-submit ... app.py --log-type=X
spark-submit ... app.py --log-type=Y
```

If you need to perform different logic based on the type, use a regular if-else statement

Comment: Once i aggregate records based on LogType, the dataframe records need to be sent to the same sink(i.e. in same Kafka topic- in production) do I need to combine the dataframes with the different LogTypes ? The 2 dataframes after aggregation will have different columns .. pls let me know your thoughts. thnx (Pls note : since this is streaming, i believe we can have only 'one' df.writeStream .. hence the 2 dataframes after aggregation need to be combined ?)

Comment: also, I'm not planning on doing multiple spark-submit commands, the data will be processed in a single spark-submit

Comment: You can use filter function more than once, I just think running multiple apps would scale better. You should also be able to writeStream multiple times, but otherwise, you'll need to union the filtered dataframes first

Comment: thanks for the inputs on this, I was able to get this working by running multiple jobs, one for each logType